# Why can't I write any code after starting a console application on Visual Studio for C#?

Tags: c#

Using Visual Studio for Mac Community Version 7.4.3 (build 10), I start a new project ("solution"), choose .NET Core App, then Console Application. After opening the new project, I get a greyed-out page with nowhere to type my code. Am I supposed to open a C# file within this solution? If so, what kind do I need if I'm looking to make a hello-world style file that will run on Visual Studio's console?

Comment: This is because the program is currently debugging, if you wish to modify the codes while it is running, then consider breakpoints in the debugger and jumping on it again and again as you change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the Program.cs file open. That is what you edit.